# methode map in class cats.data.Nested not recognized

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have a problem when folowing the scala cats library tutorial, the map method  applied to the Nested class is highlighted with red, and the compiler doesn't recognize it.

here is my main class code :

```
import cats._
import cats.data._
import cats.implicits._
import cats.syntax.functor._
import cats.Functor
import cats.instances.list._
import cats.instances.option._

object Main extends App{
  val list = List(Some(1), Some(2), None, Some(4))


  val nested: Nested[List, Option, Int] = Nested(list)
  //here is the problem
  nested.map(_ + 1)   
}
```

here is my build.sbt file

```
name := "dailySBT3"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.5"

scalacOptions += "-Ypartial-unification"

libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "1.1.0"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are importing the instances and syntax twice. The following works for me with no problems:

```
import cats._
import cats.data._
import cats.implicits._

object Main extends App{
  val list = List(Some(1), Some(2), None, Some(4))


  val nested: Nested[List, Option, Int] = Nested(list)

  nested.map(_ + 1)   
}
```

You could also do the same thing as above but get rid of the `cats.implicits._` import instead.

When in doubt, check out the [cats import guide](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/imports.html).

Comment: thank you very much, it solved the problem for me, another problem is that in intelliJ, it's always highlighted in red, i should signal it to jetbrains